# Can the minimal polynomial of a matrix have a root with multiplicity?

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Can the minimal polynomial $P$ of a square matrix over some field $F$ have the form $P=Q(X-\lambda)^2$ for some $\lambda \in F$ ?

Comment: $\pmatrix{\lambda&1\\0&\lambda}$

Comment: Yup. Any nilpotent matrix is an example.

Answer (score 2):

*Any* monic polynomial occurs as the minimal polynomial of some square matrix, in particular of its own companion matrix. Therefore, yes, multiple roots are definitely possible for minimal polynomials.